# Filter for Highest Available Time at a Day of a Pandas DataFrame Smaller Than Certain Limit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For this Python Pandas DataFrame, I would like to have that row of the day with the highest time smaller than `14h00`:

```
import pandas as pd

import datetime
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["31.12.1997 23:59:12",
                         "31.12.1998 12:59:12",
                         "31.12.1999 11:59:13",
                         "31.12.1999 12:59:13",
                         "31.12.1999 23:59:14"],
                   "b": [2,3,4, 5, 6]})
df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df.a)
df["day"]=df.date.dt.date
```

So that the result would be:

```
                     a  b                date         day
1  31.12.1998 12:59:12  3 1998-12-31 12:59:12  1998-12-31
3  31.12.1999 12:59:13  5 1999-12-31 12:59:13  1999-12-31
```

As the real DataFrame is quite big, a high execution performance would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
In [8]: df.loc[df[df.date.dt.hour.le(14)].groupby('day')['date'].idxmax()]
Out[8]:
                     a  b                date         day
1  31.12.1998 12:59:12  3 1998-12-31 12:59:12  1998-12-31
3  31.12.1999 12:59:13  5 1999-12-31 12:59:13  1999-12-31
```

---

Details

```
In [9]: df.date.dt.hour.le(14)
Out[9]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: date, dtype: bool

In [10]: df[df.date.dt.hour.le(14)]
Out[10]:
                     a  b                date         day
1  31.12.1998 12:59:12  3 1998-12-31 12:59:12  1998-12-31
2  31.12.1999 11:59:13  4 1999-12-31 11:59:13  1999-12-31
3  31.12.1999 12:59:13  5 1999-12-31 12:59:13  1999-12-31

In [11]: df[df.date.dt.hour.le(14)].groupby('day')['date'].idxmax()
Out[11]:
day
1998-12-31    1
1999-12-31    3
Name: date, dtype: int64
```